# specify only one of two parameters in a request

Tags: javascript

I am integrating Stripe subscriptions on my website and I want to use the same function for two different situation: new customer or existing customer.
In case of a new customer I will pass the customer_email parameter, in case of an existing one the customer parameter.
I am trying to implement this logic in my actual code where I pass both (and this will lead to an error). I need to remove both key and value of one.

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    customer: customer, //remove this line if new customer
    customer_email: customerEmail, //remove this line if existing customer
    line_items: [{price: planId, quantity: 1}],
    subscription_data: { 
    trial_period_days: 15
    },
    metadata: {'planId': planId,'product': product},
    success_url: `${domainURL}/index.html?product=${product}&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${domainURL}/product=${product}&index.html?session_id=cancelled` ,
    mode: 'subscription',
});
```

The workaround is to duplicate the code but I prefer to keep my code minimal where possible.
How can I remove the key:value pair conditionally?

The condition is simply:

```
if(customer!=''){
    //i have a customer id, so remove the customer_email key:value
}else{
    //new customer, remove the customer key:value
}
```

Comment: You can remove keys from objects with the `delete` operator.  Such that if you have an object like `var x = { test: 'me' }` you could `delete x.test`.  That is assuming that you put them there by default.  Otherwise, you could not add them to the object by default and then conditionally add them.  The two approaches being inverses of each other.

Comment: One way is to use destructuring. You could destructure the property you want to remove and then collect all other properties in another object using the `rest` syntax. Example: `const { propToRemove, ...restProps} = obj;`

Comment: [from the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer_email) regarding `customer_email` it says: `If provided`. You can pass the key empty and it shouldn't give any error.

Comment: Error: You may only specify one of these parameters: customer, customer_email. this is what I get @LS_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the values to undefined to omit it.

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    customer: customerEmail ? undefined : customer, //remove this line if new customer
    customer_email: customerEmail || undefined, //remove this line if existing customer
    line_items: [{price: planId, quantity: 1}],
    subscription_data: { 
    trial_period_days: 15
    },
    metadata: {'planId': planId,'product': product},
    success_url: `${domainURL}/index.html?product=${product}&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${domainURL}/product=${product}&index.html?session_id=cancelled` ,
    mode: 'subscription',
});
```

Another solution would be to extend the object conditionally.

```
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: [{price: planId, quantity: 1}],
    subscription_data: { 
    trial_period_days: 15
    },
    metadata: {'planId': planId,'product': product},
    success_url: `${domainURL}/index.html?product=${product}&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${domainURL}/product=${product}&index.html?session_id=cancelled` ,
    mode: 'subscription',
    ...(customerEmail ? { customer_email: customerEmail } : { customer })
});
```

Comment: this will remove the value but not the key. I need to remove the whole line

Comment: @LelioFaieta I provided another solution that will omit the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
const trueCondition = true;
const falseCondition = false;
const obj = {
  ...(trueCondition && { dogs: "woof" }),
  ...(falseCondition && { cats: "meow" }),
};
```

Reference: [https://amberley.dev/blog/2020-09-07-conditionally-add-to-array-or-obj/#:~:text=To%20conditionally%20add%20a%20property,use%20of%20the%20%26%26%20operator.&text=In%20the%20example%20above%2C%20in,then%20spread%20into%20the%20object](https://amberley.dev/blog/2020-09-07-conditionally-add-to-array-or-obj/#:%7E:text=To%20conditionally%20add%20a%20property,use%20of%20the%20%26%26%20operator.&text=In%20the%20example%20above%2C%20in,then%20spread%20into%20the%20object).